# How do I create a simple search function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I start with a short array of some schools and then I want to test if the value of an input matches one of these schools.
Here is my code thus far:

```
    var $schools = [
     'University of Tennessee-Knoxville',
     'Maryville College',
     'Cleveland State Community College',
     'East Tennessee State University'
    ];   
    var $searchBar = $('input.searchBar');
    $searchBar.keyup(function(){
         var $searchValue = $searchBar.val();
         for (var x = 0; x < $schools.length; x++) {
             var $schoolLC = $schools[x].toLowerCase();
             var $searchLC = $searchValue.toLowerCase();
             var $searchingValue = new RegExp('.*' + $searchLC + '.*');
             if ($schoolLC.match($searchingValue)) {
                 console.log($searchLC);
             }
         }
     });
```

But something is obviously wrong (I believe with my RegExp), because it never console.logs the $searchLC.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Which browser? Which version of jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this

```
if ($searchLC.match($searchingValue)) {
```

supposed to be

```
if ($schoolLC.match($searchingValue)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape all RegEx special characters:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

...
var $searchingValue = new RegExp('.*' + escapeRegExp($searchLC) + '.*');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms6V3/)

```
for (var x = 0; x < $schools.length; x++) {
    var $schoolLC = $schools[x].toLowerCase();
    var $searchLC = $searchValue.toLowerCase();
    var $searchingValue = new RegExp('.*' + $searchLC + '.*');
    if ($schoolLC.match($searchingValue)) {
        alert($schoolLC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for this particular example, instead of using match you can use indexOf so that your code becomes

```
var $schools = [
 'University of Tennessee-Knoxville',
 'Maryville College',
 'Cleveland State Community College',
 'East Tennessee State University'
];   
var $searchBar = $('input.searchBar');
$searchBar.keyup(function(){
     var $searchValue = $searchBar.val();
     for (var x = 0; x < $schools.length; x++) {
         var $schoolLC = $schools[x].toLowerCase();
         var $searchLC = $searchValue.toLowerCase();
         if ($schoolLC.indexOf($searchLC) >= 0) {
             console.log($searchLC);
         }
     }
 });
```